# How to get huge output of command with sshLibrary of robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am writing a robot script to run a command on DUT which produces a huge output. Manually when I run the command on DUT, it hardly takes ~20 seconds, I tried keeping different timeout values but dint work. I tried `Read Until Prompt`, but no luck.

Here is the piece of code:

```
    Write  abc
    # Set Client Configuration    timeout=30 seconds
    Set Client Configuration    prompt=abc)
    Read Until Prompt
```

When I ran it with `-L TRACE` option, I saw following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line 1161, in read_until_prompt
    return self._read_and_log(loglevel, self.current.read_until_prompt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line 1214, in _read_and_log
    raise RuntimeError(e)
```

Can someone please guide me if I am missing anything?

Comment: Can you please provide the full log and error message. If you can share what you expect (i.e. observe yourself on the CLI) and what you actually get would help.

Comment: Consider `abc` as a CLI which gives a huge output and once the execution is done, `abc)` prompt will be set.